# How to revert a software update in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, plugins

I think the last update of an Eclipse plugin is causing errors, how can I revert to the version previous to the latest update ?

(the plugin is PHPsrc : http://www.phpsrc.org/)

Thanks

Answer (score 76, accepted):

To revert, select menu Help > About Eclipse.

In the dialog box, click the Installation Details button. Then select the Installation History tab.

Now you'll see a list of previous configurations; you can select one of them, and the Revert button will be enabled.  Now you can click it to revert to the selected configuration.

Comment: @Ladlestein is it possible to do it from the command line? After plugin installation I can't run Eclipse anymore :( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8953267/revert-to-previous-configuration-from-command-line

Comment: Hi @Ladlestein I am trying this but it does not go back to the previous installation. I want to go back from ADT 23 to ADT 22.6 but after restarting Eclipse I still get the message '...needs version 23 or above'. How can I solve this? Thanks

Comment: @alvaro.delasema I don't know why that's not working. You should create a new question and post all the information there: the  versions, the sequence of actions you took, and complete error messages. If you link to it from here, I can take a look at it.

Comment: Seven years old and still relevant. I had an update today that gutted the Java Package Explorer. No packages or menus were shown - only the frame. Reverted to back before the updates, and it's back to where it was.

Comment: I faced the same issue today, but had a little difference. STS itself was not opening and was asking to update JVM from 1.8 to 11. when edited the "SpringToolSuite4.ini" and removed the config line added for required java version, then STS opened, rest from here followed the same.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem today where an update to Eclipse caused Eclipse to stop working, but found a different solution.

In my case I applied some reccomended updates, but the Eclipse restart failed.
Looking in the log file, I could see that Eclipse would not start because of a new error.

I read around (including this question, and the comment from @Denis ).

This lead me to running

```
eclipse -clean
```

This took longer than usual to start, but it did start, and I have been able to restart once more, so I think I am up and running once more.

Back posting to here in case it helps someone else !

Answer (score 0):

enter to Help -> About Eclipse

[image: enter to Help -> About Eclipse]

press on Installation details

[image: press on Installation details]

press on "installation History" and choose the version i want by date

[image: press on "installation History" and choose the version i want by date]

press **revert**