# Vertical scroll not working in Eclipse/PyDev

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

I updated today to the latest version of PyDev (2.7.2), everything went smooth, I restarted Eclipse and then the vertical scroll in the PyDev editor stoped working. The scrollbar is moving, but the text is not scrolling. The horizontal scroll works though. This happens only with python files. When I open a text file or some other kind of file (not .py) scrolling works fine.
Does anyone has any idea why this is happening and maybe how this can be fixed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATE**: A new version (2.7.3) has been released that fixes this. Try updating to that.

It's happening to me, too, and looks like a bug in the latest release. [Here's the bug report.](https://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=3608122&group_id=85796&atid=577329)

I decided to [revert to the previous version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3855814/how-to-revert-a-software-update-in-eclipse) until this issue is fixed.

Comment: Interestingly, it does not fix it for me. Eclipse 4.2, PyDev 2.7.3

Comment: But reinstalling PyDev by selecting the same version again, and using Eclipse's update dialog, fixed the issue. To summarize: Fresh Eclipse 4.2 with Pydev 2.7.3 showed the issue, refreshing the PyDev install fixed it. This is on Ubuntu 12.10, using the Oracle Java7 SDK packages, but Eclipse/Pydev installed manually

Answer (score 34):

Scrolling didn't work for me after updating to `Ubuntu 15.10` (Eclipse 4.5.1, and PyDev 4.4.0).

Resolved after setting: `Preferences --> PyDev --> Editor --> Overview Ruler Minimap --> Show vertical scrollbar`

Comment: This actually fixes it for me.  No vertical scrollbar appears, but vertical scrolling now works.  It says you have to restart the editor, but that just means any file you have open, close and re-open.

Comment: For me too. Thanks :)

Comment: i bet this was previously the same problem with a different cause. now it's coming up in newer software and this is the new answer

Answer (score 6):

Same thing happened to me. For now I uninstalled the latest version and reinstalled PyDev `2.7.1.2012100913`. This is done on Eclipse `Help->Install New Software->What is already installed?` Here you must uninstall PyDev. Then you have to go back to `Help->Install New Software` choose PyDev on the `Work with` combobox and uncheck the `Show only the latest versions of available software` option. Now you can install any older version with a working vertical scroll.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried holding CTRL while you scroll the page ? It works for me !

My environment is Eclipse Mars R2 + PyDev 5.1.2 + Ubuntu 16.04 + Python 2.7

Answer (score 0):

What OS are you running? It's not some third party java implementation causing issues? I had that problem with Eclipse behaving strange on Unix a few times.

Comment: I'm using Windows XP SP3 and Java 6 Standard Edition. Nothing unusual.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem on OS X, I added it to the bug report; hope this gets resolved soon.

Answer (score 0):

The same happened to me, but now with version 2.7.3 the bug seems to have been fixed. I have updated PyDev and it works well so far. In the [release notes](http://pydev.org/) you can see that it says:

> 2.7.3 fixes major regression regarding scrollbar.

So I hope this fixes this major bug! Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem today. Looks like this is fixed now in PyDev version 2.7.3.2013031601. Try updating your software to this version and see if that works. It worked for me.