# Limited Eclipse GUI: cannot drag windows

Tags: eclipse, user-interface, window, updates

I had installed *Eclipse* `2020-03` mostly to program in Python with *PyDev*: everything worked fine. (In Ubuntu 16.04.7)

I updated to *Eclipse IDE* `2020-06` through `Check for updates` menu. Now I cannot move (drag and drop) the windows in the workbench, nor resize them by moving the separation between them. In this situation the utility of eclipse is extreme limited.

Do you have any insight on what to do to have full windows functionality on ECLIPSE? Thanks.

Comment: Might be an GTK issue. [Eclipse 2020-06 (4.16) requires now GTK 3.20](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.16/platform_isv.php#gtk-min-version). Does an upgrade of GTK help?

Comment: Thanks for hint! It might go in the right direction. Certainly, I have version GTK `3.18.9`

Comment: @howlger your suggestion did not help with this issue, but it was a great improvement for my Ubuntu 16.04. desktop to upgrade to GTK 3.20. **I recommend it**: see [post upgrade to GTK 3.20 for Ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/933010/how-to-upgrade-gtk-3-18-to-3-20-on-ubuntu-16-04#955980)

Comment: I can confirm, that doing [those steps](https://askubuntu.com/questions/933010/how-to-upgrade-gtk-3-18-to-3-20-on-ubuntu-16-04#955980) will make the workbench windows, toolbars and toolboxes drag and drop again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Conservative Solution

The fastest way to recover the lost functionality is to [revert to the previous installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3855814/how-to-revert-a-software-update-in-eclipse) `2020-03`.
It worked fine after correcting some problems with the `eclipse.ini` file, because the `-startup` and the `--launcher.library` entry in this file are wrong.

1. **-startup entry**: To find the right `.jar` file go to the folder `plugins` which is in the [eclipse.ini directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41795137/wheres-the-location-of-the-eclipse-ini-file/63447018#63447018) (e.g., `/opt/eclipse/2020-03/eclipse`)  and copy the right name in `eclipse.ini` (in my case the right `.jar` file was `plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.5.700.v20200207-2156.jar`)
2. **--launcher.library entry**: To find the right launcher write on terminal `locate .equinox.launcher.gtk` and take the newest version of the launcher, which is usually found in `~/.p2/pool/plugins/` (in my case the right launcher was `~/.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.1200.v20200508-1552` )

Sadly, this is not a full solution, because I have to give up the newest version `2020-06` :_(

Comment: I did hit the same issue. Thanks for the post!